# What is the right way to use FormSpy in React Final Form as an alternative to Redux-Form isDirty?

Tags: reactjs, redux-form, final-form

I have a large (3+ year old) React Redux project which uses a lot of [Redux-Form](https://redux-form.com/8.3.0/). As that is now discontinued I am doing new features in [react-final-form](https://final-form.org/react/). It has been pretty easy to move to final-form but I was using some advanced features of redux-form that have no equivalent in final-form. I need a component that is outside of the form to know when the form is dirty, submitting etc.

Final-form suggests FormSpy for this, which works, but I have come up against React's Warning:

`Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within render)`

So, really, this is as much a React as a Final-Form question. I have put an example app below illustrating the problem. In summary a parent Component `<Parent/>` renders a bunch of child components. One of those is a final-form instance `<TheForm/>`, one of the other child components, `<ShowFormState/>`, renders the form's state (eg whether the form is dirty). Importantly `ShowFormState` is a sibling of the form, not within it. In Redux-Form this was simple: `ShowFormState` could just grab the form's state from redux but final-form has no equivalent so the `Parent` uses FormSpy's `onChange()` and stores the state in it's own state and passes that to its child `ShowFormState` as props.

React no likey and I get the above error (which after 3 years of working in React I have not seen before!). The warning is totally understandable, that is not the question. I am just a bit stuck on how to work around it, with the given structure.

The sample App is below, I hope it is clear enough :). Anyone who has migrated from redux-form to final-form bumped into a similar problem?

```js
import React , {Component} from 'react'
import {Form, FormSpy, Field } from 'react-final-form' 

class Parent extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {}
  }

  onSubmit = () => { console.log("Submitted!") }

  onChange = ({dirty}) => {
    // triggers rerender DURING render so cant do this
    this.setState({ dirty })
  }

  render = () => (
    <>
      <TheForm
        onChange={this.onChange}
        onSubmit={this.onSubmit}
        />
      {/*other components ...*/}
      <ShowFormState dirty={this.state.dirty}/>
    </>
  )
}

const ShowFormState = ({dirty}) => dirty ? <p>dirty!</p> : null

const TheForm = ({onChange, onSubmit}) => (
  <Form
    onSubmit={onSubmit}
    initialValues={{ name:'' }}>
    {({ handleSubmit }) => (
      <form className="wrap" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Name:
          <Field name="name" component="input"/>
        </label>
        {<FormSpy onChange={onChange}/>}
      </form>
    )}
  </Form>
)

function App() {
  return <Parent /> 
}

export default App;
```

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: Ok in the end I worked out _a_ solution. The parent _onChange_ pushed the change to redux rather than state (so a render was not triggered) ,  I then connected ShowFormState to redux :P, not super tidy but it means I can at least carry on with the migration to Final Form!